# In XSLT replace value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have this XML document :Now I want to replace LineNo so that the output will be line no will 1 ,2 . I have tried some thing like this.

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace( '000010',1)"/>
<Rder> 
   <Order>
      <OrderNo>458</OrderNo>
      <LineNo>000010</LineNo>
      <SerialNO>96</SerialNO>
       <VNo>543</VNo>
      </Order>
     <Order>
     <OrderNo>458</OrderNo>
     <LineNo>000020</LineNo>
     <SerialNO>32</SerialNO>
     <VNo>543</VNo>
     </Order>
</Rder>
I want to replace the value of LineNo= 000010 ,000020 by 1,2 in XSLT below  one i  have tried.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:key name="orders" match="Order" use="OrderNo" />
<xsl:template match="/*">
      <SalesOrders>
        <xsl:for-each select="Rder/Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('orders', OrderNo)[1])]">
          <Order VNo="{VNo}" OrderNo="{OrderNo}"> 
            <OrderLines>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('orders', OrderNo)" />
            </OrderLines>
          </Order>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </SalesOrders>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Order">
        <OrderLine  LineNo="{LineNo}" SerialNO="{SerialNO}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actually  I getting those lineno  details in same  format i have  tried couple cases its doesn't  giving that expected format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to replace `<LineNo>000010</LineNo>` by `<LineNo>1</LineNo>` because you want to strip all `0` digits or because its parent `Order` element is the first in its group?

Comment: If you're using XSLT 2.0, why don't you use `xsl:for-each-group`?

Comment: Yes Martin Exactly but  that one  we need dynamically its should be  like  if it is coming 000010 ---> or 000020--> 000030 --->3

Comment: Michael  could  you  tell me  how we can use i don't have much idea on xslt. xsl:for-each-group?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xslt-2.0]+for-each-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="Order">
    <OrderLine  LineNo="{position()}" SerialNO="{SerialNO}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

or:

```
<xsl:template match="Order">
    <OrderLine  LineNo="{number(LineNo) div 10}" SerialNO="{SerialNO}"/>
</xsl:template>
```